# Finding Consecutive Items in List using Linq

Tags: linq

Say I have the following array of integers:

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 6, 4, 10, 9, 12, 15, 17, 8, 3, 20, 21, 2, 23, 25, 27, 5, 67,33, 13, 8, 12, 41, 5 };
```

How could I write a Linq query that finds 3 **consecutive** elements that are, say, greater than 10? Also, it would be nice if I could specify I want say the first, second, third etc. group of such elements.

For example, the Linq query should be able to identify:
12,15,17 as the first group of consecutive elements
23,25,27 as the second group
67,33,13 as the third group

The query should return to me the 2nd group if I specify I want the 2nd group of 3 consecutive elements.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**UPDATE:** While not technically a "linq query" as Patrick points out in the comments, this solution is reusable, flexible, and generic.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication32
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] numbers = { 1, 6, 4, 10, 9, 12, 15, 17, 8, 3, 20, 21, 2, 23, 25, 27, 5, 67,33, 13, 8, 12, 41, 5 };

            var consecutiveGroups = numbers.FindConsecutiveGroups((x) => x > 10, 3);

            foreach (var group in consecutiveGroups)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", group));
            }
        }        
    }

    public static class Extensions
    {
        public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> FindConsecutiveGroups<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Predicate<T> predicate, int count)
        {
            IEnumerable<T> current = sequence;

            while (current.Count() > count)
            {
                IEnumerable<T> window = current.Take(count);

                if (window.Where(x => predicate(x)).Count() >= count)
                    yield return window;

                current = current.Skip(1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
12,15,17
23,25,27
67,33,13
```

To get the 2nd group, change:

```
var consecutiveGroups = numbers.FindConsecutiveGroups((x) => x > 10, 3);
```

To:

```
var consecutiveGroups = numbers.FindConsecutiveGroups((x) => x > 10, 3).Skip(1).Take(1);
```

**UPDATE 2** After tweaking this in our production use, the following implementation is far faster as the count of items in the numbers array grows larger.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> FindConsecutiveGroups<T>(this IEnumerable<T> sequence, Predicate<T> predicate, int sequenceSize)
{
    IEnumerable<T> window = Enumerable.Empty<T>();

    int count = 0;

    foreach (var item in sequence)
    {
        if (predicate(item))
        {
            window = window.Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(item, 1));
            count++;

            if (count == sequenceSize)
            {
                yield return window;
                window = window.Skip(1);
                count--;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            count = 0;
            window = Enumerable.Empty<T>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Patrick, technically it isn't a "linq query" but if you remove the using System.Linq; line, this won't work, hence it is Linq, just not in the form of a query. And it is more flexible in this way. Solves the problem in a reusable fashion.

Comment: @Patrick - True, this is not a Linq query, but it does allow me to execute a Linq query to accomplish what I need to do.

Answer (score 3):

```
int[] numbers = { 1, 6, 4, 10, 9, 12, 15, 17, 8, 3, 20, 21, 2, 23, 25, 27, 5, 67, 33, 13, 8, 12, 41, 5 };

var numbersQuery = numbers.Select((x, index) => new { Index = index, Value = x});

var query = from n in numbersQuery
            from n2 in numbersQuery.Where(x => n.Index == x.Index - 1).DefaultIfEmpty()
            from n3 in numbersQuery.Where(x => n.Index == x.Index - 2).DefaultIfEmpty()
            where n.Value > 10
            where n2 != null && n2.Value > 10
            where n3 != null && n3.Value > 10
            select new
            {
              Value1 = n.Value,
              Value2 = n2.Value,
              Value3 = n3.Value
            };
```

In order to specify which group, you can call the `Skip` method

```
query.Skip(1)
```

Comment: Very Nice!  one big LINQ query.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try this extension method?

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Consecutives<T>(this IEnumerable<T> numbers, int ranges, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    IEnumerable<T> ordered = numbers.OrderBy(a => a).Where(predicate);
    decimal n = Decimal.Divide(ordered.Count(), ranges);
    decimal max = Math.Ceiling(n); // or Math.Floor(n) if you want
    return from i in Enumerable.Range(0, (int)max)
           select ordered.Skip(i * ranges).Take(ranges);
}
```

The only thing to improve could be the call to `Count` method because causes the enumeration of `numbers` (so the query loses its laziness).

Anyway I'm sure this could fit your `linqness` requirements.

**EDIT:** Alternatively this is the *less words* version (it doesn't make use of Count method):

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Consecutives<T>(this IEnumerable<T> numbers, int ranges, Func<T, bool> predicate)
{
    var ordered = numbers.OrderBy(a => a);
    return ordered.Where(predicate)
                  .Select((element, i) => ordered.Skip(i * ranges).Take(ranges))
                  .TakeWhile(Enumerable.Any);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do this for a list of doubles. There is an upper as well as a lower limit. This is also not a true Linq solution, it is just a pragmatic approach I wrote this in scripting language that only implements a subset of C#.

```
var sequence =
 [0.25,0.5,0.5,0.5,0.7,0.8,0.7,0.9,0.5,0.5,0.8,0.8,0.5,0.5,0.65,0.65,0.65,0.65,0.65,0.65,0.65];
double lowerLimit = 0.1;
double upperLimit = 0.6;
int minWindowLength = 3;

// return type is a list of lists
var windows = [[0.0]];
windows.Clear();

int consec = 0;
int index = 0;

while (index < sequence.Count){

        // store segments here
        var window = new System.Collections.Generic.List<double>();

        while ((index < sequence.Count) && (sequence[index] > upperLimit || sequence[index] < lowerLimit)) {        
            window.Add(sequence[index]);
            consec = consec + 1;
            index = index +1;
        }

        if (consec > minWindowLength) {
            windows.Add(window);
        }

        window = new System.Collections.Generic.List<double>();
        consec = 0;

        index = index+1;
}

return windows;
```