# Getting last x consecutive items with LINQ

Tags: c#, .net, linq

My question is similar to this one: [Finding Consecutive Items in List using Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7112435/finding-consecutive-items-in-list-using-linq).  Except, I'd like to get the last consecutive items that have no gaps.  For example:

```
2, 4, 7, 8
```

output

```
7,8
```

Another example:

```
4,5,8,10,11,12
```

output

```
10,11,12
```

How can that be done?

Comment: Why is the result for the second example not 10,11,12?

Comment: the best answer will depend on your collection Type.

Comment: And why do you want to do this with Linq?

Comment: Sorry - second example should have been 10,11,12.

Comment: @Cameron: Why do it in Linq? Because it's a problem well suited to Linq?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm assuming in that you want the last consecutive sequence with more than one member... so from the sequence

```
{4, 5, 8, 10, 11, 12, 15}
```

you're expecting the sequence:

```
{10, 11, 12}
```

I've indicated the line to remove if the last sequence is permitted to have only a single member, giving a sequence of

```
{15}
```

Here's the linq:

```
new[] {4, 5, 8, 10, 11, 12, 15}
    .Select((n,i) => new {n, i})
    .GroupBy(x => x.n - x.i) //this line will group consecutive nums in the seq
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1) //remove this line if the seq {15} is expected
    .Select(x => x.Select(xx => xx.n))
    .LastOrDefault()
```

There's a hidden assumption here that the numbers of the sequence are in ascending order. If this isn't the case, it will be necessary to enroll the powers of microsoft's extension method for [finding contiguous items in a sequence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138361.aspx). Let me know if this is the case.

Comment: +1 grouping by the number minus the index is a very slick trick

Comment: +1 for clever answer (the trick above), but I'd hate to use this method on a large list considering `GroupBy` inefficiency.

Answer (score 3):

This works and is probably easier and more efficient than LINQ in this case:

```
var list = new[] { 2, 4, 7, 8 };
List<int> lastConsecutive = new List<int>();
for (int i = list.Length - 1; i > 0; i--)
{
    lastConsecutive.Add(list[i]);
    if (list[i] - 1 != list[i - 1])
        break;
    if(i==1 && list[i] - 1 == list[i - 1]) // needed since we're iterating just until 1
        lastConsecutive.Add(list[0]);
}
lastConsecutive.Reverse();
```

Answer (score 1):

I realise this is both late and wordy, but this is probably the fastest method here that still uses LINQ.

Test lists:

```
var list1 = new List<int> {2,4,7,8};
var list2 = new List<int> {4,5,8,10,11,12,15};
```

The method:

```
public List<int> LastConsecutive(List<int> list)
{
    var rev = list.AsEnumerable().Reverse();

    var res = rev.Zip(rev.Skip(1), (l, r) => new { left = l, right = r, diff = (l - r) })
                 .SkipWhile(x => x.diff != 1)
                 .TakeWhile(x => x.diff == 1);

    return res.Take(1).Select(x => x.left)
              .Concat(res.Select(x => x.right))
              .Reverse().ToList();
}
```

This one goes from back to front and checks elements pairwise, only taking elements from when they start being consecutive (the `SkipWhile`) until they end being consecutive (the `TakeWhile`).

Then it does some work to pull the relevant pairwise numbers out (left number from the 'original' list and then all the right numbers), and reverses it back. Similar efficiency to the imperative version, but in my opinion simpler to read because of LINQ.

Comment: There something wrong with your .Zip() syntax.  It think you are trying to supply three parameters.

Comment: I'm pasting that exactly as is and it works just fine for me. Check your copying. This is .NET 4.0.