# How to capture matches and mismatches in c# regex?

Tags: c#, regex

I have some format of message for example:

```
"?I?Message message message\r\n"
```

Now I would like to capture this message by regex using named groups:

```
(?<Message>\?(?<Type>\S)\?(?<Text>[\S\s]+(\r\n)+))
```

But I would like to have also all strings which does not match this message format. For example:

```
"Some data?I?Message message\r\nAnother part of data\n"
```

would give me 3 matches:

- "Some data"
- ?I?Message message\r\n
- "Another part of data\n"

I could check if Message group has Success field set to true to check whether any message of mentioned format occurs. Otherwise I woule have some "raw data".
Is it possible to do something like this using regex and Matches ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it:

```
var str = "Some data?I?Message message\r\nAnother part of data\n";
var unmatchedCharIndices = Enumerable.Range(0, str.Length);
foreach (Match match in Regex.Matches(str, @"(?<Message>\?(?<Type>\S)\?(?<Text>[\S\s]+(\r\n)+))"))
{
    unmatchedCharIndices = unmatchedCharIndices.Except(Enumerable.Range(match.Index, match.Length));
    //do other stuff with match
}
var unmatchedStrings = unmatchedCharIndices
            .Select((n, i) => new { n, i })
            .GroupBy(x => x.n - x.i) //this line will group consecutive nums in the seq
            .Select(x => str.Substring(x.First().n, x.Count()));
foreach (var unmatchedString in unmatchedStrings)
{
    //do something with non-match text
}
```

(`unmatchedStrings` code thanks to [Getting last x consecutive items with LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10359069/getting-last-x-consecutive-items-with-linq) for a start)

Comment: Ok so that would work for my example input data but would not for this example: "Some data?I?Message message\r\nAnother part of data\n"

Comment: Modified again, I found some code to group the unmatched char indices into their strings.

Answer (score 0):

The result object from `Regex.Match` is of type [`Match`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.aspx). Its `Success` property shows if the regex *as a whole* matched.

But there is also a `Groups` property that you can use to look at the individual, named or not, capture groups. If a named capture failed to match then that's group's `Success` property will be false.

So with

```
var m = Regex.Match("Fubar", "(?<x>Z)?.*");
```

then

```
m.Success
```

is true, but

```
m.Groups['Z'].Success
```

is false.

With `Regex.Matches` the regex can match multiple times, each match will be a single `Match` object in the returned `MatchCollection`. *But* the regex will by default skip over input sections that don't match, hence:

```
Regex.Matches("ZaZ", "Z")
```

will return a collection of two matches, but nothing for the "`a`". You can force the next match to start immediately after the previous with the `\G` anchor.

Answer (score 0):

`To match mismatches`

```
string toSearchString = "your string here";

Match match = new Regex("*some pattern here*").Match(toSearchString );

string unmatchedString = toSearchString.Replace(match.Value,"");
```

So now you have the Unmatched String. you can have coffee!!