# Find Consecutive tags in a string

Tags: c#, xml, regex, parsing

```
<NNP>This is</NNP><NNP>a</NNP><NNP>test</NNP><VBD>application</VBD><NN>to </NN><NNP>find</NNP><NN>Consecutive</NN><NN>tags content</NN><IN>tags may vary.</IN> <NNP>using </NNP><NNP>C#</NNP>
```

Desired output:

```
This is a test
Consecutive tags content
using C#
```

I would like to find consecutive tags content from a string using c# (regex).

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Maybe [regular expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1336590) will- *ouch*, don't hit me! -- seriously though, is this from a real xml or html?

Comment: SO is not kind of *"Write this code for me"* site.

Comment: No it is not nested. This is not xml and html format.

Comment: You could use LINQ-To-XML, you just need to fix it by wrapping it in another single root like: `HtmlContent = string.Format("<root>{0}</root>", HtmlContent)`. Then you could [MS implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138361.aspx) or [others](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7112516/284240) to group by consecutive elements.

Comment: i know the basic in linq. Could you please post the code using linq?

Comment: Am new to stackoverflow.com. How to open it?

Comment: @Karthik: now it's open ;) You cannot open it but the community (since you've imporved it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Linq-To-XML`. But you need to fix first the invalid xml with multiple root elements:

```
string xml = "<NNP>This is</NNP><NNP>a</NNP><NNP>test</NNP><VBD>application</VBD><NN>to </NN><NNP>find</NNP><NN>Consecutive</NN><NN>tags content</NN><IN>tags may vary.</IN> <NNP>using </NNP><NNP>C#</NNP>";
xml = string.Format("<root>{0}</root>", xml); // wrapper for illegal root
```

Now you can use `XElement.Parse`:

```
XElement xelement = XElement.Parse(xml);
```

I use [Microsofts implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138361.aspx) of consecutive groupings (extension added at the end).

Then this neat query works:

```
var groups = xelement.Elements()
    .ChunkBy(x => x.Name.LocalName)
    .Where(g => g.Count() > 1)
    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
    .Select(g => new{
            Tag = g.Key,
            Value = string.Join(" ", g.Select(x => x.Value)),
            Count = g.Count()
    });
```

quick test:

```
foreach (var group in groups)
    Console.WriteLine("Tag: {0} Count: {1} Value: {2}",
        group.Tag, group.Count, group.Value);
```

output:

```
Tag: NNP Count: 3 Value: This is a test
Tag: NN  Count: 2 Value: Consecutive tags content
Tag: NNP Count: 2 Value: using  C#
```

Consecutive grouping extension [from MS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138361.aspx):

```
public static class ConsecutiveGrouping
{
    public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>> ChunkBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        return source.ChunkBy(keySelector, EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>> ChunkBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        // Flag to signal end of source sequence. 
        const bool noMoreSourceElements = true;

        // Auto-generated iterator for the source array.        
        var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();

        // Move to the first element in the source sequence. 
        if (!enumerator.MoveNext()) yield break;

        // Iterate through source sequence and create a copy of each Chunk. 
        // On each pass, the iterator advances to the first element of the next "Chunk" 
        // in the source sequence. This loop corresponds to the outer foreach loop that 
        // executes the query.
        Chunk<TKey, TSource> current = null;
        while (true)
        {
            // Get the key for the current Chunk. The source iterator will churn through 
            // the source sequence until it finds an element with a key that doesn't match. 
            var key = keySelector(enumerator.Current);

            // Make a new Chunk (group) object that initially has one GroupItem, which is a copy of the current source element.
            current = new Chunk<TKey, TSource>(key, enumerator, value => comparer.Equals(key, keySelector(value)));

            // Return the Chunk. A Chunk is an IGrouping<TKey,TSource>, which is the return value of the ChunkBy method. 
            // At this point the Chunk only has the first element in its source sequence. The remaining elements will be 
            // returned only when the client code foreach's over this chunk. See Chunk.GetEnumerator for more info. 
            yield return current;

            // Check to see whether (a) the chunk has made a copy of all its source elements or  
            // (b) the iterator has reached the end of the source sequence. If the caller uses an inner 
            // foreach loop to iterate the chunk items, and that loop ran to completion, 
            // then the Chunk.GetEnumerator method will already have made 
            // copies of all chunk items before we get here. If the Chunk.GetEnumerator loop did not 
            // enumerate all elements in the chunk, we need to do it here to avoid corrupting the iterator 
            // for clients that may be calling us on a separate thread. 
            if (current.CopyAllChunkElements() == noMoreSourceElements)
            {
                yield break;
            }
        }
    }

    // A Chunk is a contiguous group of one or more source elements that have the same key. A Chunk  
    // has a key and a list of ChunkItem objects, which are copies of the elements in the source sequence. 
    class Chunk<TKey, TSource> : IGrouping<TKey, TSource>
    {
        // INVARIANT: DoneCopyingChunk == true ||  
        //   (predicate != null && predicate(enumerator.Current) && current.Value == enumerator.Current) 

        // A Chunk has a linked list of ChunkItems, which represent the elements in the current chunk. Each ChunkItem 
        // has a reference to the next ChunkItem in the list. 
        class ChunkItem
        {
            public ChunkItem(TSource value)
            {
                Value = value;
            }
            public readonly TSource Value;
            public ChunkItem Next = null;
        }
        // The value that is used to determine matching elements 
        private readonly TKey key;

        // Stores a reference to the enumerator for the source sequence 
        private IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator;

        // A reference to the predicate that is used to compare keys. 
        private Func<TSource, bool> predicate;

        // Stores the contents of the first source element that 
        // belongs with this chunk. 
        private readonly ChunkItem head;

        // End of the list. It is repositioned each time a new 
        // ChunkItem is added. 
        private ChunkItem tail;

        // Flag to indicate the source iterator has reached the end of the source sequence. 
        internal bool isLastSourceElement = false;

        // Private object for thread syncronization 
        private object m_Lock;

        // REQUIRES: enumerator != null && predicate != null 
        public Chunk(TKey key, IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
        {
            this.key = key;
            this.enumerator = enumerator;
            this.predicate = predicate;

            // A Chunk always contains at least one element.
            head = new ChunkItem(enumerator.Current);

            // The end and beginning are the same until the list contains > 1 elements.
            tail = head;

            m_Lock = new object();
        }

        // Indicates that all chunk elements have been copied to the list of ChunkItems,  
        // and the source enumerator is either at the end, or else on an element with a new key. 
        // the tail of the linked list is set to null in the CopyNextChunkElement method if the 
        // key of the next element does not match the current chunk's key, or there are no more elements in the source. 
        private bool DoneCopyingChunk { get { return tail == null; } }

        // Adds one ChunkItem to the current group 
        // REQUIRES: !DoneCopyingChunk && lock(this) 
        private void CopyNextChunkElement()
        {
            // Try to advance the iterator on the source sequence. 
            // If MoveNext returns false we are at the end, and isLastSourceElement is set to true
            isLastSourceElement = !enumerator.MoveNext();

            // If we are (a) at the end of the source, or (b) at the end of the current chunk 
            // then null out the enumerator and predicate for reuse with the next chunk. 
            if (isLastSourceElement || !predicate(enumerator.Current))
            {
                enumerator = null;
                predicate = null;
            }
            else
            {
                tail.Next = new ChunkItem(enumerator.Current);
            }

            // tail will be null if we are at the end of the chunk elements 
            // This check is made in DoneCopyingChunk.
            tail = tail.Next;
        }

        // Called after the end of the last chunk was reached. It first checks whether 
        // there are more elements in the source sequence. If there are, it  
        // Returns true if enumerator for this chunk was exhausted. 
        internal bool CopyAllChunkElements()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                lock (m_Lock)
                {
                    if (DoneCopyingChunk)
                    {
                        // If isLastSourceElement is false, 
                        // it signals to the outer iterator 
                        // to continue iterating. 
                        return isLastSourceElement;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        CopyNextChunkElement();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public TKey Key { get { return key; } }

        // Invoked by the inner foreach loop. This method stays just one step ahead 
        // of the client requests. It adds the next element of the chunk only after 
        // the clients requests the last element in the list so far. 
        public IEnumerator<TSource> GetEnumerator()
        {
            //Specify the initial element to enumerate.
            ChunkItem current = head;

            // There should always be at least one ChunkItem in a Chunk. 
            while (current != null)
            {
                // Yield the current item in the list. 
                yield return current.Value;

                // Copy the next item from the source sequence,  
                // if we are at the end of our local list. 
                lock (m_Lock)
                {
                    if (current == tail)
                    {
                        CopyNextChunkElement();
                    }
                }

                // Move to the next ChunkItem in the list.
                current = current.Next;
            }
        }

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'string.Join(string, string[])' has some invalid arguments 
Error 2 Argument '2': cannot convert from 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'string[]' it shows these errors in string.join. what is my mistake? please guide me.

Comment: i have used .netframework 3.5 and now i've changed to 4. The error has gone.

Comment: @Karthik: you are probably using .NET 3.5 (VS 2008), is that correct? Then you don't have the `String.Join` overload that takes all `IEnumerable<T>` but only one which takes a `string[]`. Try this instead: `string.Join(" ", g.Select(x => x.Value).ToArray())`. **Edit** Ok, it's better to use .NET 4 ;)

Comment: Thanks for your timely help. Do you know how to remove some special characters in xml like ↨, →, ♫(any special charaters like this)? Thanks again.

Comment: What kind of special characters? Do you have a blacklist or a whitelist?

Comment: However, just write a method `CleanString` amd implement it according to your needs. You could either use regex or a `StringBuilder` to remove the unwanted characters. Store them in a collection(like `char[]` or `HashSet<Char>`). You can then use: `string.Join(" ", g.Select(x => CleanString(x.Value)))`

Comment: Blacklist. In my xml, <finance> 23<456 </finance>. i had the problem when i load in XElement. i used Regex to replace content using CDATA.  Regex exp = new Regex(@"<([\w\.\-]+)>(.+)</([\w\.\);
strReader = exp.Replace(strReader, "<$1><![CDATA[$2]]></$1>"); but i found some special character "∟" inside tag. How to replace or remove?